# How to Add a generic type to a component accept data as a props ( data might have different types)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have a data grid component I use it in 4 pages, so I'm passing the data as props, my problem is the data might be different and have different types. As example:

TUsers is { data:[{username: 'myName'}] }

TProducts is { data:[{productname: 'prod'}] }

case 1: `DataGrid(data: TUsers)`

case 2: `DataGrid(data: TProducts)`

I tried to create a new type have a part of my types:

```
type TCData = Partial<TUsers | TProducts>
```

but what if I have a hundred of types like TUsers, TProducts, TCustomers .. etc

I tried with ( any ) type until someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define your type like this:

```
interface myGenericType<T> {
    // here your props
}
```

and pass it to your component this way:

```
function myComponent<T extends { id: number, name: string}>(props: myGenericType<T>)
```